# Is there a name for these sequences of subsets of a commutative ring resembling the definition of a graded algebra?

Tags: commutative-algebra, terminology, graded-rings

(I am experimenting with writing arrows backwards.)

Let $R$ denote a commutative ring. Is there a term for those sequences $A : \mathcal{P}(R) \leftarrow \mathbb{N}$ satisfying the following requirements resembling the definition of a [graded ring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graded_ring#Graded_algebra)?

1. $A_i A_j \subseteq A_{i+j}$ and $1 \in A_0$
2. $A_i + A_i \subseteq A_i$ and $0 \in A_i$
3. $RA_i \subseteq A_i$

*Example.* Let $R = \mathbb{Z},$ $A_0 = \mathbb{Z}$, and $A_i = 2\mathbb{Z}$ for all $i>0$.

**Motivation.**

If a sequence $A$ into $\mathcal{P}(R)$ satisfies these conditions, then the following subset of the polynomial algebra $R[x]$ is in fact an $R$-subalgebra:

$$\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\sum_{i < n}A_i x^i$$

Comment: What's the point with writing arrows backwards?

Comment: @PedroTamaroff, given morphisms $g : Z \leftarrow Y$ and $f:Y \leftarrow X,$ their composite $g \circ f$ has type $Z \leftarrow X$.

Comment: OK. ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: There is the notion of a filtration of a ring/module. This leads to the notions of associated graded ring, blowup algebra, Rees algebra, completion, Artin-Rees lemma...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 and 3 ensures that the $A_i$'s are (left) ideals of $R$, and 1 that $A_0 = R$. Such a sequence is called a *filtration* of the unital ring $R$ by (left) ideals. More generally, you have the notion of *filtration* of an (left) $R$-module by a sequence of $R$-submodules. Endowed with such a filtration, your object is called a *filtered ring* or *filtered module*. If this filtration has some monotonicity property (like being increasing or decreasing) you can define a graded object (ring or module) associated to the filtered object.

Comment: Is it really the case that $i \leq j$ implies $A_j \subseteq A_i$ for all such sequences $A$?

Comment: No, it doesn't. Adding this gives you a *non-increasing filtration*. Typically, filtering polynomial by degree gives you an increasing filtration, which is therefore not non-increasing, that is, which doesn't satisfy what you just wrote above. Tensor algebra of a module gives you an example of a filtration which is not increasing nor non-increasing.

Comment: @Robert Green: What's called a graded ring is the associated object $\bigoplus_{i\ge 0}A_i/A_{i+1}$ (for a non-increasing filtration), not the filtered ring itself. Similarly for modules.